# TinyMCE 3.5.8: Detailed Steps for Creating a Button that Acquires a Value from User and Inserts it Between a Pair of Tags

Tags: button, tinymce

TinyMCE 3.5.8

I merely need to create a button (and module) that acquires a user-entered value from a popup and places it between two tags, e.g., [bib][/bib]

I am having trouble finding a "step-by-step" for doing this, including what files, where code goes, etc.  This must be rather simple?

I have replaced all of the occurrences of "example" with my module name in the "Example" module, but that is where my information ends.

If someone would be so kind !

P.S.:  It would be even better if the form field would javascript validate for "integer", but maybe I ask too much?

Answer (score 0):

1. download the tinymce development version
2. use tiny_mce_dev.js instead of tinymce.js for developement in order to get more usefull error messages
3. create an [own tinymce plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/creating_a_plugin) (this is not that difficult) that opens a [popup](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aclass.tinyMCEPopup)
4. get the content of a popup field
5. insert it at the right place in the editor

You should have a look at other tinymce plugins (in the plugins directory under the tiny_mce dir) to get to know how some things work. There are many plugins, some of them use popups.
I.E. the searchreplace popup